# Convolution equivalent to matrix multiplication?

Tags: convolution

Is it possible to write the full convolution between the image and the filter as a matrix multiplication operation? If so, can someone give a simple example of how that works?

Comment: did you think about your homework question at all? what does matrix multiplication look like in closed form? what does convolution look like in matrix form? that would give you the idea.

Comment: What I have thought about so far is to use a System of linear equations, am i on the right track?

Comment: the right track is understanding that discrete-time convolution in one of your two dimensions is a dot product.  for each row you do a dot product.  then you do a similar dot product (if your filter is the same in the x or y direction) for each column of pixels.